# UINavigationBar title gets clipped while changing viewControllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

When I push a new tableViewController from the starting screen of the iOS app (I push the Settings screen) the title in the UINavigationController gets clipped until the animation finishes:

[image]

That is the NavigationBar in mid animation, and just before the animation finishes, it looks like this:

[image]

After a moment, the title changes correctly to "Settings". It's not a big deal, but you can imagine how much it bothers a slightly OCD-prone programmer! :)

Here's the code in the tableViewController where I set the title, nothing special:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Settings";
        // Hide tabBar when pushed so you cannot switch from the Settings
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I also have this annoying problem. In my case I'm using a custom font for the navigation title and setting them using setTitleTextAttributes:forState:, it doesn't happen if I don't change it. Also, this "issue" seems to be fixed in iOS6. I'd love to find a work around, that's why I started a bounty to bring some attention...

Comment: Can you put bg.png on dropbox or similar?

Comment: Have you subclassed any of the following: `UINavigationBar`, `UINavigationItem`, `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Yes, this issue is fixed in iOS 6. The answer fixes it for iOS 5 as well, at least in my case.

I haven't subclassed anything, I was just using the UIAppearance to globally change the look of UINavigationBars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit late with the answer, but I tracked down the issue on iOS 5.. When you use the UIAppearance proxy on UINavigationBar, it appears you need to explicitly set the font size, instead of using 0.0 to let it auto set based on orientation.

I was able to fix this by subclassing UINavigationController and putting in the following code:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // You should include a conditional here to check for iOS 5, so iOS 6 doesn't have to do any additional work
    self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{
        UITextAttributeFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) || IS_IPAD ? 20.0f : 16.0f],
        UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor],
        UITextAttributeTextShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.5f],
        UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset:[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, -1.0f)]
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, putting the font size to a hard-coded value fixed the problem.

This was the previous code:
`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Akzidenz-Grotesk BQ" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];`

And I just changed the font size to a fixed value:

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Akzidenz-Grotesk BQ" size:22.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];`

Works like a charm now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
self.navigationItem.title = self.title;
```

in the viewWillAppear method

Answer (score 0):

try

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.title = @"Settings";
}
```

Comment: As an aside, per [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:), "[i]f you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation."